# jQuery Mobile Header - How to repeat-x a bg and put an image on?

Tags: jquery, css, image, mobile, repeat

I need to setup my header. I'm trying to `repeat-x` a background and put an image on with no luck.

**HTML:**

```
<div data-role="page" id="page1">
<div data-role="header">
    <div><img src="jquery-mobile/images/logo.png" class="ui-header"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
    .ui-header{
    background-image: url(http://www.mybizonline.co.il/book/tno/jquery-mobile/images/bg.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat-x; 
    width: 1024px;
    height: 275px;
}
```

Its should look like this:
[image: Intended look]

**bg repeated to x, image on the bg**

Does anyone have idea why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

html:

```
<div data-role="page" id="page1">
<div id="bg_wrapper" data-role="header">
    <img src="jquery-mobile/images/logo.png" class="ui-header">
</div>
```

css:

```
#bg_wrapper {
    background: url('...') repeat-x;
    text-align: center;  // To center your img
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the background-image to your img if you add

display: block

to the CSS but I would suggest applying the ui-header class to the div wrapping your image instead:

http://jsfiddle.net/8mv7V/

```
<div data-role="page" id="page1">
<div data-role="header">
<div class="ui-header"><img src="http://www.mybizonline.co.il/book/tno/jquery-mobile/images/logo.png"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.ui-header
{
background-image: url(http://www.mybizonline.co.il/book/tno/jquery-mobile/images/bg.jpg);
background-repeat: repeat-x;
height: 462px;
text-align: center;
}
```

(P.S. I think your background image, bg.jpg, might be 8px off at the top)

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for your time! here what I did:
http://jsfiddle.net/VYHQU/

in jsfiddle its looks fine, but when i'm trying to load it with http://ipadpeek.com/ its doesn't look so good:

http://www.mybizonline.co.il/book/tno/jquery-mobile/images/stack1.PNG

what i did wrong?

Comment: I think your heights are a bit off in the CSS - logo.png is 338px so unless you're trying to do something using overflow try adjusting that (and crop the bg.jpg image - I did it with background-position in the CSS but it's cleaner to alter the image itself): http://jsfiddle.net/VYHQU/2/

Comment: can I solve it with CSS code?
There is any way to remove the <img src=""> code from the HTML and fix it only via CSS? I mean, load both pictures by 275 height to the center?

Its still doesn't looks via iPad :/

Answer (score 0):

For this `you have to do some work on image resizing`, i have done what you are trying to do:

```
.ui-header{
   background: url(http://www.mybizonline.co.il/book/tno/jquery-mobile/images/bg.jpg) 0 -60px repeat-x; 
   width:500px;
   height: 275px;
   padding:0 254px;
   text-align:center;
}
```

**`you can find out here:` http://jsbin.com/aduxum/5/edit**